# vue-grid-layout: update only a specific grid-item

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a big project for our company in which our clients are able to add (and delete) their own personal dashboards. Within these dashboards they have the ability to add all kinds of analyses we sell.

To make this work I'm using [vue-grid-layout](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout).

In my database I have all the tables which store the dashboards for each user and also which analysis they've added to their dashboards.

My routine(s) work fast and fine. After a user enters our portal, I fill their dashboards form the back-end `API`. The `API` gives me a `JSON` response with the users dashboards and analyses (which are in fact `vue` components). for example:

```
[
  {
   "did":1,
   "dname":"Dashboard name",
   "ddesc":"Description of the dashboard",
   "is_active":1,
   "dashboardViews":[
       {
        "x":0,
        "y":0,
        "w":6,
        "h":15,
        "i":4,
        "comp":"c-specific-component"
       }
    ]
   }
]
```

I use `bootstrap-vue` for my front-end frame work. I use tabs for the users dashboard and populate them with this `v-for` loop:

```
<b-tab v-for="dash in dashViews" :key="dash.did" :title="dash.dname" :active="dash.is_active === 1" title-item-class="custom-tab-title">
    <b-row class="row-padding-margin">
        <b-col lg="12">
            <b-btn size="md" :variant="themeVariant.colDanger" class="button-margin float-right" @click="showDeleteDashboardModal(dash.did)"><icon name="trash-alt" /> Delete dashboard</b-btn>
            <b-btn size="md" :variant="themeVariant.colPrimary" class="button-margin float-right" @click="editDashboard(dash.did)"><icon name="edit" /> Rename dashboard</b-btn>
            <b-btn size="md" :variant="themeVariant.colSecondary" class="button-margin float-right" @click="editDashboard(dash.did)"><icon name="share-alt" /> Share dashboard</b-btn>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row class="row-padding" style="margin-bottom: -10px">
        <b-col lg="12">
            <b-alert variant="default" :class="themeVariant.alertStyle" show>{{ dash.ddesc }}</b-alert>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <!-- DASHBOARD CONTENT WITH DRAGGABLE AND RESPONSIVE GRID -->
    <grid-layout
            :layout.sync="dash.dashboardViews"
            :col-num="6"
            :row-height="30"
            :is-draggable="true"
            :is-resizable="true"
            :is-mirrored="false"
            :vertical-compact="true"
            :margin="[10, 10]"
            :use-css-transforms="false"
            :responsive="true"
            @layout-updated="layoutUpdatedEvent">
        <grid-item v-for="view in dash.dashboardViews"
                   :key="view.i"
                   :x="view.x"
                   :y="view.y"
                   :w="view.w"
                   :h="view.h"
                   :i="view.i"
                   @resized="resizedEvent"
                   @moved="movedEvent">
            <component :is="view.comp" class="component-settings-grid"></component>
        </grid-item>
    </grid-layout>
</b-tab>
```

My `dashViews` data object is a `computed property`.

My "problem": when the user deletes a dashboard, the whole `dashViews` gets populated again (ofcourse: `vue`'s reactivity).

I was wondering: can I prevent this and only remove the dashboard thats deleted (in combination with a `POST` to the back-end to tell my `db` that the dashboard is deleted)?

Comment: I figured out that I can use `push` and `splice` to adjust my `dashViews`. Still working on this, thus will place the final code (and therefore solution) later on.

Answer (score 0):

So like I said in the comment: I use `splice` and `push` to get to the result I prefer.

When the user adds a dashboard, I send the settings for the dashboard to my `API` and insert it in the `db`. when the `API` gives me a 200 `http`, response I push the dashboard to the `dashViews` array (using a `vuex` mutation):

```
pushNewDashBoard(state, data) {
    state.dashViews.push(data);
    state.nodata = false;
}
```

When the user deletes a dashboard I also send the action to my backend `API`. Again, when I get a 200 `http` response I also delete the dashboard form the array like so (also using a `vuex` mutation):

```
removeDashboard(state, id) {
    let index = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < state.dashViews.length; ++i) {
        if (state.dashViews[i].did === id) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index > -1) {
        state.dashViews.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

The above mentioned methods save me form re-building the whole `dashViews` every time a user deletes or adds a dashboard.